# English words and Sentences Dictionary

Tags: android, mysql, database, dictionary

I want to develop a keyboard app for android like swiftkey. I am looking for a dictionary database that not just have words but can predict sentences as well like if I type in **"how"**, it could suggest sentences like:

```
1) how are you
2) how do you do
3) how about that
```

Any guidance will be helpful, I would like the dictionary to be in `.txt`, `.csv` or `mysql` database. Please suggest how I can accomplish this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Databases like this are not for free. I would start by scanning BBC or CNN pages and putting those into database. Later you can use your users typing.

Comment: well that's a nice idea, thanks! Also if you know any paid service to get such a database please tell me.Thanks!